# Generate timestamp column from date and hour columns in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark data frame which looks something like this

| loc | date | hour | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-28 | 1 | 23.7 |
| 1 | 2023-10-28 | 2 | 34 |

What I want to have is an additional column which represent date and hour a single timestamp value. For example:

`2023-10-28` and `1` would become `2023-10-28 01:00:00`.

I tried in many ways but just doesn't work. One that I expected to work without any issues is using a UDF:

from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

```
def buildTimestamp(date,hour):
    y = F.year(date)
    m = F.month(date)
    d = F.dayofmonth(date)

    return datetime(y, m, d, h) # expected to be: 2023-10-28 01:00:00
buildTimestampUDF = udf(lambda d, h:buildTimestamp(d,h))
```

and then in the code I have .withColumn like this:

```
new_df = df.withColumn('current_ts', buildTimestampUDF(col('date'), col('hour'))
```

I get an error:

> An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack
> trace below. Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "", line 11, in  File
> "", line 6, in buildTimestamp File
> "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line
> 1747, in year return
> Column(sc._jvm.functions.year(_to_java_column(col))) AttributeError:
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

I really don't understand the error. I guess it is something with the UDF itself but not sure. Tried to add an additional check at the top of the function whether any of the arguments is None but still same error.

Comment: Could this be about the datetime() function ? the error is pointing at the line where you return datetime, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

hour_str = F.concat(F.col('hour'), F.lit(':00:00'))
time_str = F.concat(F.col('date'), F.lit(' '), hour_str)
time_col = time_str.cast("timestamp")

df_new = df.withColumn("current_ts", time_col)
df_new.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Let us use `make_interval`

```
df = df.withColumn('current_ts', F.expr("to_timestamp(date) + make_interval(0, 0, 0, 0, hour, 0, 0)"))
```

Alternatively you can simply concat the hour with date then convert to timestamp

```
df = df.withColumn('current_ts', F.expr("to_timestamp(date  || ' ' || hour)"))
```

---

```
+---+----------+----+----+-------------------+
|loc|      date|hour| val|         current_ts|
+---+----------+----+----+-------------------+
|  1|2023-10-28|   1|23.7|2023-10-28 01:00:00|
|  1|2023-10-28|   2|34.0|2023-10-28 02:00:00|
+---+----------+----+----+-------------------+
```